# React JS: How can I export different components based on environment variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

React JS code:

I want the `src/app.jsx` to do `export default App` when the `REACT_APP_AUTH_SERVER` variable in `.env` does not exist or have other value, and do `export default withAuthenticator(App)` when the `REACT_APP_AUTH_SERVER` variable in `.env` does exist, and has value `aws-cognito`:

`src/app.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SecuredGate from './SecuredGate/SecuredGate';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import './App.css';
import '../fontStyles.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SecuredGate />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Result = () => {
  if (process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_SERVER && process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_SERVER === "aws-cognito"){
    return withAuthenticator(App);
  } 
  return App;
}


// export default App;
// export default withAuthenticator(App)

export default Result;
```

However, this is not working.

If I do:

```
export default App;
// export default withAuthenticator(App)
```

, it works, and if I do:

```
// export default App;
export default withAuthenticator(App)
```

it works as well.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Should you calculate this on runtime or build time?

Comment: @fgkolf I'm not sure what it means... I just run it with `yarn start`

Comment: Looks like you want to `export default Result();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `Result` component returns a component instead of an element. To understand this better look at what `App` component does when called with `<App />`. It runs the code in its body and returns some markup. But what happens if you call `<Result />`. It will run the code in its block and return another component (a function). So to solve this you can try:

```js
const Result = (process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_SERVER && process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_SERVER === "aws-cognito")
    ? withAuthenticator(App)
    : App;
}

export default Result;
```

Comment: Thanks !    I just solved the problem with the same method.